# How do I combine a number of images into a single PDF using ruby?

Tags: ruby, pdf, pdf-generation, rmagick

I have an array of images. How can I combine them into a PDF, with one image per page?

I've taken a look at RGhost and RMagic and the answer might be in there somewhere but it's eluding me right now.

Comment: take a look into `prawn` gem

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use RMagick's [`ImageList#write`](http://www.imagemagick.org/RMagick/doc/ilist.html#write):

> If the image format indicated by the filename supports multiple images per file (animated images), write writes all the images in the imagelist to a single file.

Example:

```
require 'rmagick'

image_list = Magick::ImageList.new("image1.png", "image2.png", "image3.png")
image_list.write("images.pdf")
```

Comment: That looks good Stefan. Just a quick question. If I have an array of images, how do I pass that across? The array translates to Magick::ImageList.new(['image1.png', 'image2.png']) which doesn't work. If I convert to a string I get Magick::ImageList.new("'image1.png', 'image2.png'") which also doesn't work. I probably missing an obvious trick here.

Comment: It doesn't work for me as I use `Magick::ImageList.new(["image1.png", "image2.png"])`

Comment: @MinhDanh You have to pass the filenames, not an array, i.e. `Magick::ImageList.new('image1.png', 'image2.png')`

Comment: Oh, I thought you were mentioning about array by `Magick::ImageList.new(*array)`

Comment: @MinhDanh That would work, too. The `*` converts the array into an argument list. In your case: `Magick::ImageList.new(*['image1.png', 'image2.png'])` (note the `*` in front of the array)

Comment: @Stefan Thank you

Comment: when used with pdfs, the resolution decreases a lot, do you know any way to preserve it?

Comment: answering myself: for anyone having quality issues with this (probably with pdfs), you can set the density: `pdf = Magick::ImageList.new("file_name.pdf") {self.density="300"}`

Comment: If you use this method, it will work, but it will be very resource consuming, and if the pdf file is heavy, the system will be overloaded. Is there another more optimal way? Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

Have a look into [`prawn`](http://prawn.majesticseacreature.com/) gem. Simple example see below:

```
require 'prawn'

Prawn::Document.generate('hello.pdf') do |pdf|
   pdf.text("Hello Prawn!")
   pdf.image "#{Prawn::DATADIR}/images/fractal.jpg", :at => [200, 100]
end
```

Comment: This gem is awesome! Thanks